# Get SMS Subscriber Count By Area Code

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, subscriber

I want the mobile connect SMS subscriber count by area code to visualize them on a map.

I've checked the Data View: **SubscriberSMS** to find is there any field like a "Locale" which will help me to identify an area of the subscriber but I've not found any filed except the mobile number which may help to get the area of the subscriber.

Is there any best way to get the count of SMS subscribers by area code?

Answer (score 1):

The Locale field type is used for Mobile Connect and can only contain country codes.

If you try to add something to the field in Contact Builder that is not a country code, you will get a tip like this:

> This locale field requires valid locale values (such as FR or ES-ES).

When it comes to geographic data, there is no internal way of identifying anything else than the country based on the mobile data that is in Mobile Connect - mobile numbers are not bound to any area code.

Segmentation done by area code is only possible if you ask the client for that data and store that in a connected CRM platform.